# How to send files as arguments in docker for python cli application?

Tags: python, docker, command-line-interface

I'm trying to send files as an argument in python3 cli app (which uses argp arse for parsing) which is hosted in docker. But I'm getting OSError:

> Error opening b'input_file.txt' when I perform docker run -t
>   input_file.txt

I tried:

```
docker run -t docker_image_name input_file.txt
```

My docker file has entry point as:

```
ENTRYPOINT [ "python", "/src/cli_app.py" ]
```

Comment: Does the file exist **inside** the Docker container?

Comment: No it doesn't exist. First answer in this thread worked.

Answer (score 1):

You're telling your python application to look for `input_file.txt`, but that file doesn't exist in the container. You're not passing a *file* as is, just an *argument/parameter*. Try the following to mount your local file (I'm assuming it's in your working directory) into the container:

```
docker run -it -v $(pwd)/input_file.txt:/tmp/input_file.txt docker_image_name /tmp/input_file.txt
```

Comment: This works. How to I get converted file from above program named as 'output.txt' to my local directory?

Answer (score 0):

```
docker run docker_image_name -e IP_FILE_NAME="input_file.txt"
```

In your python code access the filename as environment variable $IP_FILE_NAME. This is considering the input_file.txt is present in the container. Use COPY command to copy the file from the machine you use to build to the container.

```
COPY input_file.txt /src/input_file.txt
```